# What is the syntax to filter a group of tasks by a given label name?

Tags: syntax, jira, jql

I am very new to Jira and could not find an answer for this very simple request: I want to see only the tasks which are labeled with a given label, say "label1".

The closest syntax I could find is the following:

```
labels = "label1"
```

But if the task has other labels than "label1", they don't show.

Thank you for any help

Comment: The query that you mentioned is going to show all the issues that have "label1" label. If some of these issues have other labels along with "label1", they will be displayed too. Are you trying to exclude the issues with multiple labels?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
labels in (label1)
```